# 'Compile Sources' not updated while dragging files to a project in Xcode 4.3.2

Tags: xcode

I am just not sure if this is a bug in Xcode 4.3.2 or is it supposed to be this way.

When I upgraded to Xcode 4.3.2 some time back and dragged some files onto a newly created project, it repeatedly threw linker errors while compiling. All the required frameworks were already linked. Turned out, that these errors disappeared when I went and manually added the .m files that I had manually dragged onto the project, in the Build Settings - Compile Sources.

I have done the same thing in previous versions of Xcode and never had to update the manually update the compile sources myself. I would assume that if any .m file is dragged into the project, the compile sources should be automatically updated.

I don't have any previous version Xcode currently available with me where I can test it, but would like to know if this really is a bug in Xcode 4.3.2 or is there something else that I am missing.

Comment: Ok, realized that 'Add to Targets' needs to be checked while dragging files on to the project.

Comment: With new xcode 4 never ever add files by drag and drop better use "Add Files to "YourProject"" option.

Answer (score 5):

'Add to Targets' needs to be checked while dragging files on to the project.

Comment: Where does one find this setting? To clarify, I'm not getting the popup that one usually gets when dragging files.

Comment: @arik File-> Add files to...

Comment: I vaguely recall finding that option back then and that finally forcing Xcode to show the dialog. It could probably be a related question/answer.

Answer (score 0):

First : whatever Thunder Rabbit said

Second: I never encountered any problems dragging the .m file but i did encountered problems by dragging an SDK file such as for twitter etc. For that I had to change the library search path in Build Settings.

Third: I also encountered Strip errors in one of the SDKs, the solution of which I mentioned in this question: [error in generating archives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642210/error-in-generating-archives/12741793#12741793)

Hope the information helps