# Error in generating Archives

Tags: ios, archive, aviary

I m using Xcode 4.2 and i have add AviarySDK 2.4.4 in my project.
Application runs fine in Simulator 5.0 and 4.3. I also test it on device having ios 4.1. So i want to generate .ipa file for my client. But by some reason it can not generate Archives.
It gives following error

"/usr/bin/strip -S /Applications/Projects/AppName/AppName/AviarySDK/Resources/AviarySDKResources.bundle/AviarySDKResources -o /Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WDYWT-avjpbcnwjylobvgevipvsqttnopd/ArchiveIntermediates/WDYWT/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/WDYWT.app/AviarySDKResources.bundle/AviarySDKResources

/usr/bin/strip: for architecture armv7 object: /Applications/Projects/AppName/AppName/AviarySDK/Resources/AviarySDKResources.bundle/AviarySDKResources malformed object (unknown load command 10)

error: strip /Applications/Projects/AppName/AppName/AviarySDK/Resources/AviarySDKResources.bundle/AviarySDKResources: /usr/bin/strip exited with 1
"

Any help will really great. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strip errors are generally caused if you have duplicate debugging symbols in your project. Just try the following:

**First Method:**

1. Go to build settings of your project
2. Type `Strip` in the search Bar.
3. Under `Strip Debug Symbols During Copy`, you shall find `Debug` and under that you shall find `Any SDK`.
4. Select `NO` in `Any SDK`, select `YES` in `Debug` and select `YES` in `Strip Debug Symbols during copy`.
5. A little below you shall find `Use Separate Strip`. Select YES`.`
6. Check that `Strip Style` should remain `All Symbols` [If not then change it to that].

**Second Method:**

> Since your error also mentions derived data, their might me duplicacy of your derived data as well. Delete Your project file from the derived data folder.
>   If you don't know where the derived data folder is, Google it.

I am using aviary in my current project. I have a Mac Mini and a MacAir [for work at home].
I was facing the same strip issues with aviary which I resolved using the first method mentioned above.

It took me a week to figure this out cuz i am a relative newbie in development and nothing regarding this issue has been mentioned in aviary forums as well.

PS:

```
MacMini: Xcode 4.5
MacAir: Xcode 4.2
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Your first Method works, but i wonder why it dose not cause any problem with old version of Aviary....

Comment: even i dont know abt that although they have mentioned that the latest version [ the version which you and I are using ] have some bug fixes for iOS, but, I believe its the other way round :P